# Scorm package only marked as "complete" not "passed"

Tags: moodle

I'm having trouble about setting a Scorm package to be "passed" when students reach the minimum passing grade. The Scorm's status is just completed even if I have reached 100 points. I need the package to be marked passed so students can access their certificate with their grade on it.

I'm using iSpring Suite 8 as the quiz maker sofrware

Answer (score 0):

If the SCORM is registering "completed" instead of "passed" when someone finishes with a passing score, this usually means a change is necessary to the progress reporting settings in iSpring (Storyline, Captivate, and other authoring tools include similar settings when publishing the package.)

These settings should be in the window that appears when you publish your SCORM package and choose the LMS settings. My version of iSpring may differ from yours, but the window should look similar to this in iSpring:

[image: a]

From the LMS tab in the publishing window you will want to:

- Choose "Customize" for the Progress and Completion settings
- Change the value for "Report status to LMS as" to "Passed/Incomplete" or "Passed/Failed"
- Republish your SCORM package and re-upload it to Moodle (or whichever LMS / LRS / LXP you are using)

Even if these settings are correct, sometimes changes are also needed to completion rules for the activity or course in Moodle (or whichever LMS / LRS / LXP you are using), although it sounds like you already have that set the way you need it.